# fit container of resized image with fixed ratio

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I scale down by using a div container. Unfortunately the container adapts the width of the full size of the image. How can I make the container fit the containing image?

```css
.container {
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://compass-ssl.microsoft.com/assets/bc/84/bc84e95b-76b9-4b24-ad5f-9748a2d75b1b.svg?n=microsoft_account_logo_color.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the container `display:inline-block` and it will collapse to the width of the contents.

```css
.container {
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://compass-ssl.microsoft.com/assets/bc/84/bc84e95b-76b9-4b24-ad5f-9748a2d75b1b.svg?n=microsoft_account_logo_color.svg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ha, Beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.container {
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://compass-ssl.microsoft.com/assets/bc/84/bc84e95b-76b9-4b24-ad5f-9748a2d75b1b.svg?n=microsoft_account_logo_color.svg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `.container` `display: inline-flex`:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://compass-ssl.microsoft.com/assets/bc/84/bc84e95b-76b9-4b24-ad5f-9748a2d75b1b.svg?n=microsoft_account_logo_color.svg" alt="">
</div>
```